# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'freeImplementation()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had this error when I build and sync my old Android project on updated to the latest version of android studio.

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'freeImplementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Naqda_mobile' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.2 and sync project

The project 'Naqda_mobile' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Comment: post your Gradle as well

Comment: Upgrade your plugin version to 3.4.2.  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`